# Direction of Centripetal Force in a Rotating Wheel

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

While looking at the solution of the question I came upon this figure,
[image]

My doubt is why is the centripetal acceleration $\omega^2r$ towards the center of the wheel C instead of IAOR of the wheel i.e. the bottommost point?

Answer (score 1):

Improving @Kshitij answer a bit, the centripetal acceleration is indeed towards IAOR when you are working in that frame and it's magnitude is $\omega^2r$ where $r=\sqrt2R$, but you need to consider the component of it in the horizontal direction for writing the respective force equations $F_{x}=Ma_{cm}$
i.e, ($\omega^2\sqrt2R)cos45^\circ=\omega^2R$. So you were mistaken about the component. Also, to add, the distance between the particle and center of hoop is constant, so the particle is performing circular motion about the center of hoop and so you can directly say that it has an centripetal acceleration $\omega^2R$ towards center of the hoop. So you get it by both ways.

Answer (score 0):

We can calculate, velocity and acceleration of the point on sphere, with respect to IOAR, but you would have to know the distance (or magnitude of position vector wrt IOAR) between point of IOAR, and the point where you need to find the motion quantities, which would be cumbersome.

For example, if you calculate velocity at the point you marked, in figure, with respect to IOAR, with help of little geometry, you can easily find $r_{dist}=\sqrt{2} r$
Hence we get $v=ωr\sqrt {2}$
We will get same result wrt centre of sphere, by resolving vectors, and finding magnitude.

So we prefer to work wrt sphere's center, for calculating
motion quantities, since magnitude of position vectors wrt centre, of any point on surface are equal (radius), which eases calculation.

Comment: my doubt is why is centripetal acceleration not towards the IAOR

Answer (score 0):

In any inertial frame of reference, the accelerations depend on real forces and are the same as they are in other inertial frames.

But the IAOR is frame dependent because the translation velocity is frame dependent.

In your example (where I'm assuming the wheel has constant velocity), the IAOR point in the ground frame (the bottom of the circle) must be accelerating upward. So this isn't a special point that has zero acceleration or where all acceleration points.

Instead the accelerations are all identical to that of the wheel in the COM-at-rest frame.  The acceleration of every point is directed to the center of the wheel as required by uniform circular motion.